# Should I expand my code making it easier to read, or leave as is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-formatting, memory-efficient

I study computer science at GCSE. I can code reasonably confidently, I just can't get my head around making my code more efficient.

For example, the line `music = [[a,s] for a,s in (x.split(':') for x in open("conf/music.txt").read().split("\n"))]` seems efficient to me, but obviously I have a different idea to everyone else.

I suppose what I am asking, is: Is it generally better to expand my code making it easier to read, even if more variables are created because of this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT:
Is this (below) a better solution?

`with open("conf/music.txt") as f:
    fr = f.read()
    e = fr.split("\n")
    fl =  [[a,s] for a,s in (x.split(":") for x in e)]`

Again, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/satwikkansal/python-practices-for-efficient-code-performance-memory-and-usability-aze6oiq65

Comment: You're not going to get much of a hit by expanding your code lines. The addition of a line or two is linear and ultimately won't matter a whole lot.

Usually, when it comes to efficiency, we're looking at iterating over large data sets or something like that, where you can optimize by reducing the amount of times  you traverse the object. Look into Big O efficiency, that might clear things up for you.

Comment: Why do you think your assumption about what efficiency means is disproved by what you've been told about a *different* property of the code you're writing?

Comment: besides, opening a file without being able to control when it's closed is a big no-no

Comment: @jonrsharpe Both clarity of code and efficiency seem to come up together regularly, and I wondered if there was going to be any sort of performance hit.

Comment: I don't think the amount of lines of code you write has anything to do with how much memory it consumes or how *efficient* it is. Using the right data structures and algorithms, however, very much does. That said, for humans, readable code is much much better than clever looking code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, normally I would use with open() as:, but it seemed more efficient to do it this way. I remember reading somewhere that as long as it isn't assigned to a variable, Python will discard it as soon as it is out of use, not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: as long as it doesn't compromise code quality, i also favor these one-liners. Its funny when people talk about python 'readability' but then they create unnecessary functions and classes .... and talk about assigning readable titles those functions ... its like reading page 1 in a book which then tells you to skip to page 10, page 10 says to go to page 6 ... and so on

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thought exactly, I think from now on I may just make two versions of the same code, one of each extreme, and offer them both as a solution. Thanks

Comment: Your code is inefficient, it materialized a large string, then a list, when you don't have to do that at all. In my experience, this is the problem with using one-liners. It is better to learn to actually use Python data structures efficiently

Comment: @SamCole you can use readline instead reading everything

Comment: @Shankar no, just iterate over the file object directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to you use WITH clause in python which is more pythonic and simple to read.

```
with open("welcome.txt") as file: # Use file to refer to the file object
    file.readline()
    #do something with data
```

https://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/
https://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post to contain what I think is a more suitable solution :)

Comment: @SamCole Please accept the solution

Comment: @SamCole Please accept if its useful to you

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-file-handling